# Adjust Google Analytics behavior based on consent

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics based on consent, so the user is not tracked and the GA cookies are not set until after they accept the cookies. I'm using the following code:

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
                'ad_storage': 'denied',
                'analytics_storage': 'denied'
                });
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX', { 'anonymize_ip': true, 'cookie_expires': 0 });
</script>
<!-- End Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->


<script type="text/javascript">
   
    __tcfapi('addEventListener', 2, function(tcData, success) {
     if (success && tcData.gdprApplies && (tcData.eventStatus === 'tcloaded' || tcData.eventStatus === 'useractioncomplete') ) {
        if (tcData.purpose.consents[1]) {
  
            gtag('consent', 'update', {
      'ad_storage': 'granted',
      'analytics_storage': 'granted'
    })
        } 
        
     }
    })
    </script>
```

This code works great in Chrome, but it's not tracking correctly in Safari. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can please you describe what you mean by "not tracking correctly"? Do the cookies not get set after giving consent? Do you know if the `__tcfapi` event listener gets called? What is the behavior you are expecting and what is actually happening?